# How do you handle live streaming buffering with the Flutter just_audio plugin?

Tags: flutter, live-streaming, just-audio

I am building a live streaming radio app and I've decided to use the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) plugin along with the [just_audio background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background) plugin.

It seems to work well but my client has reported back that the app sometimes buffers a lot when users are out and about and with poor network connection or if they are not on fast data plans. I could be wrong but I think this might be because it's always streaming audio at the highest quality.

Is there any good way to handle this? Is there something I forgot to set? Is there a way to lower the audio quality if the user is buffering so not as much data is used? I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the quality of the streaming so that it can load fast. Add the field in the extras inside media item as below:

```dart
extras: {
  'url': song['path'].toString(),
  'subtitle': song['subtitle'],
  'quality': song['quality'], 
},
```

Comment: How would I lower the quality depending on the buffering status though?